# Formal offer letter delay (after verbal offer)

Tags: job-offer, new-job, recruitment

My friend got a verbal offer from one company last Tuesday (Sept 29) and they said the formal letter will be sent in a couple days. He sent them an email on Friday asking whether they had sent it and he had missed it and that he had another offer he had to decide on. The HR responded saying 'It is in que to be sent out to you'. He hasn't got it yet (note that this office operates in California time zone). The verbal offer said the deciding deadline was 15 Oct.

Anyone had a similar experience? I asked this on reddit and another individual said he/she was in the same situation with VMware - they had been accepted for the same position. The program is the University Launch program. Just wanting to know if this is normal or is it something to be worried about

Edit: He got the letter late afternoon yesterday (Thurs Oct 8)

Comment: When is the deadline for the other offer?

Comment: Removed specific mention of company as that makes this question off-topic.

Comment: Deadline for other offer is 15th Oct too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: What is the actionable question here?

Comment: Question is whether anyone had a similiar experience and what eventually happened/ is this normal. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 4):

Usually, any written offer letter will come with a deadline (to respond) of X amount of time after the offer has been made formally, i.e., after the written offer is extended. If there's a delay, it's most likely that the confirmation deadline will also get extended proportionately.

As for deciding between two offers - that's a more personal call. What we can say is two things:

- A verbal offer means nothing, unless you get a written offer letter/ confirmation and have an acceptance recorded (email/ physical copy).
- If the first offer does not arrive in a formal manner before the second offer response deadline, based on how important is the offer (it's a choice or necessity to accept one/any job) you need to take the call whether to accept the second one or wait for the first one to arrive.

If the first one (which is yet to arrive) is the preferred choice, I strongly suggest following up with them - call them up if you have the number of the recruiter / HR/ Contact person, don't wait up for email response.

Comment: The HR did respond to his email on Friday saying it is in que to send out - if it doesn't come by EOD today he will contact them again.

Comment: +1 for the first bullet.  Until they actually send the formal written offer, your friend does not have an offer.  My PERSONAL recommendation is for your friend to assume that their offer has evaporated, and continue his job search.  If he already has an acceptable written offer in front of him, from another firm, he should seriously consider taking it, and notifying company A that he is no longer available.  It sounds as though the delay might well be helping your friend dodge a bullet.

Comment: He got the formal letter on Thurs, Oct 8 :)